# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: asp.net

If i do a PostBack check the whole RadioButtonList dissapears on index changed.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="PollOptionsRadioButtonList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
```

EnableViewState="true" />

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            PollOptionsRadioButtonList.SelectedIndexChanged += PollOptionsRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged; 

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {                   
            RenderPollOptions(poll);
            }

    }
    private void RenderPollOptions(Poll poll)
    {
        foreach (string option in poll.Options)
        {
            var optionItem = new ListItem();
            optionItem.Text = option;
            optionItem.Value = poll.Options.IndexOf(option).ToString();             
            PollOptionsRadioButtonList.Items.Add(optionItem);
        }
    }
    protected void PollOptionsRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = 2;

    }
```

POLL CLASS

```
        [EPiServerDataStore(AutomaticallyCreateStore = true, AutomaticallyRemapStore = true)]
public class Poll: IDynamicData
{
        public Identity Id { get; set; }

        public string Question { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores all answes to this poll
    /// </summary>
        public List<PollAnswer> Answers { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public List<string> Options { get; set; }

        public Poll()
        {
            Answers = new List<PollAnswer>();
            Options = new List<string>();
        }


}
```

Comment: can you post the code of Poll Class??

Comment: Can you please explain What's your problem clearly and Also expected OutPut?

Comment: Why are yau adding the event handler on code behind. Any reason for that?

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli To separate code from mark up. Its a code standard praxis where i work.

Comment: @VigneshKumar When i click one of the options a postback occurs, but the event handler is not triggered. And then the readiobuttons are gone. But this is only because the items are added from code. If i add the items in the mark up page it works.

Comment: If it's a standard practice where you work, why not ask a colleague who can actually look at it?

Comment: Do you have `EnableViewState="false"` in the .aspx? That would cause this as the radiobuttons would not store the options.

Comment: @pete This was it! It seemed that it was false as default. so i have to set it to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason  EnableViewState was defaulting to false!

`<%@ Page EnableViewState="true" >`

fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

May you need to add `AutoPostback` Property as well:

```
 PollOptionsRadioButtonList.AutoPostback = True;
```

Comment: I have that as well. :(
I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the items on every postback, wrap it in a `PostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PollOptionsRadioButtonList.SelectedIndexChanged += PollOptionsRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged; 
    if(!IsPostBack)
        RenderPollOptions(poll);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It doesnt work. Ive tried that. When i do the PostBack check the whole RadioButtonList dissapears on index changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Your code, The mistake is Only on adding item. so i have inclide **IsPostBack** Method()

Try Like This

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="PollOptionsRadioButtonList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"

EnableViewState="true" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        PollOptionsRadioButtonList.SelectedIndexChanged += PollOptionsRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged; 
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RenderPollOptions(poll);
        }
}
private void RenderPollOptions(Poll poll)
{
    foreach (string option in poll.Options)
    {
        var optionItem = new ListItem();
        optionItem.Text = option;
        optionItem.Value = poll.Options.IndexOf(option).ToString();             
        PollOptionsRadioButtonList.Items.Add(optionItem);
    }
}
protected void PollOptionsRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = 2;

}
```

Comment: Sorry but i already have a postback check. ... ill add it to the question so no one else will be confused. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It says Page not found